# Почему определение, относящееся к личному местоимению, обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, определения, местоимения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему обособляются согласованные определения, относящиеся к личным местоимениям? Они даже интонационно как-то очень самостоятельны? Лично я в них вижу обстоятельственный оттенок. Почему так? Заранее спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, но всегда интересно порассуждать. Для меня обособленные определения ближе к  предикатам, хотя их и можно заменить на обстоятельство, с "будучи/являясь", например. А он, мятежный, просит бури... А он, будучи мятежным, просит бури... А он мятежный, и он просит бури...
Может быть, согласованные определения уже в некотором виде содержат в себе местоимения, окончания - это же вроде некогда "приросшие" местоимения-артикли, причем определенные, а личные местоимения только указывают на лица. Насколько сочетается определенный артикль с таким словом? Не называющим, а указывающим, не получается ли какого-то конфликта при этом известного и неизвестного?